# Python Flask Render_Template get/set variable

Tags: python, html, flask

I couldn't quite find what I was looking for online, so I'm hoping maybe someone could better explain this.

I have a button that does a POST method to pick a model of a car. After you choose the model it creates several different buttons below for different trims. This all works great, but I need to determine the "model" that was chosen first. So I'd like to be able to send set a variable, and send it on the render_template. Essentially, what I need is to be able to

```
 def order_page(model=None):
     ORDERCONFIGURATORLABEL = "Please Select one of the available Models below"
     CAR_DATA = [
    {'name': 'Model 3', 'trim': ['Standard Range', 'Long Range']},
    {'name': 'Model Y', 'trim': ['Standard Range', 'Long Range']},
    {'name': 'Model S', 'trim': ['Standard Range', 'Long Range']},
    {'name': 'Model X', 'trim':['Standard Range', 'Long Range']}

     ]
     if request.method == "POST":


      if request.form.get("Model 3 Button"):
        
        CAR_DATA = [
            {'name': 'Model 3', 'trim': 'Standard Range', 'price': '$35,000', 'picture':'model3.png'},
            {'name': 'Model 3', 'trim': 'Standard Range Plus', 'price': '$39,990', 'picture':'model3.png'},
            {'name': 'Model 3', 'trim': 'Mid Range', 'price': '$45,000', 'picture':'model3.png'},
            {'name': 'Model 3', 'trim': 'Long Range', 'price': '$49,990', 'picture':'model3.png'},
            {'name': 'Model 3', 'trim': 'Performance', 'price': '$56,990', 'picture':'model3.png'}]

        return render_template("order.html", model="model3", CAR_DATA=CAR_DATA,ORDERCONFIGURATORLABEL = "", currentmodel = "Model 3",SELECTEDMODELLABEL="Great choice! Please select your trim.", currentcarimage=r"model3.png")
```

I could obviously type in /order/model3 but I need to be able to set this link within python. Is there anyway I could use render_template to set /order/ or am I completely using this incorrectly?

So simply, I first check if the button sent the value "Model 3 Button", but when I click on the second button for trim, I lose that value. Is there anyway to save or "preserve" that data into my next POST method?

Here's my layout.html

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>{{title}}</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', 
 filename='css/main.css') }}">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="description" content={{description}}>
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
   </head>

   <body >
     {% include 'navigation.html' %}
     {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   </body>

 </html>
```

and my order.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

 {% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1 text-align: center> {{title}}</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p>{{paragraph1}}</p>
        <p>{{paragraph2}}</p>
    </div>
    
</div>

        <div class="column c80">
            
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=currentcarimage) }}" class="carimage" alt=""  />
            <footer>$49000</footer>
            
        </div>

        <div class="column c20">
            <h1 > Model Selector </h1>
            <label class="clabel" >{{ORDERCONFIGURATORLABEL}}</label>

            <div class="mybuttonparent">
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="mybuttonparent">
            
            

            <form method="POST" action="/order">         
            <button  class="btn" type="submit" name="Model 3 Button" value="Model 3 Button">Model 3</button>
            </form>
               
            </div>
            
            <div class="mybuttonparent">
                <form method="POST" action="/order">         
                    <button  class="btn" type="submit" name="Model Y Button" value="Model Y Button">Model Y</button>
                    </form>
                            
            </div>
            <div class="mybuttonparent">
                <form method="POST" action="/order">         
                    <button  class="btn" type="submit" name="Model S Button" value="Model S Button">Model S</button>
                    </form>
                            
            </div>

            <div class="mybuttonparent">
                <form method="POST" action="/order">         
                    <button  class="btn" type="submit" name="Model X Button" value="Model X Button">Model X</button>
                    </form>
                            
            </div>
            <div><h2>{{currentmodel}}</h2></div>
            <div><label class="clabel">{{SELECTEDMODELLABEL}}</label></div>

            {% for trim in CAR_DATA%}
            <div class="mybuttonparent">
                <form method="POST" action="/order">         
                    <button  class="btn" type="submit" name='{{trim.trim}}' value='{{trim.trim}}'>{{trim.trim}}</button>
                    </form>
                            
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

{% endblock %}

I tried using the

```
 <input  name="userselectedcar" value={{selectedmodel}} id="userselectedcar" />
```

and tried getting the value to check, but it's null.

```
 carmodeltype = request.form.get("userselectedcar")
```

I passed selectedmodel into my render_template, and I can see it in the input. THen when I click on the second button, I seem to lose it because carmodeltype == None, not my model i chose ("model3")

Comment: Share the template please.

Comment: just added the two html templates

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to render `hidden` field in **every** form you want to get back the data on the "server" side.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="car_model" name="car_model" value="{model_goes_here}}">
```

Comment: So i've tried doing that, but I can't seem to get the value of the input.

Comment: carmodeltype = request.form.get("userselectedcar")        
            if carmodeltype.value == "model3" :

Comment: just gives me null. Sorry lol, I'll just update my question to show the whole thing lol

Comment: So you have added another field to the form with the value you need. You post the form but you dont get the data on the Flask side?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to follow - can you explain the status?

Comment: So I click on my first button (Model 3), then click on the trim button (Long Range). I need to be able to know what button I clicked before the trim button (Model 3) I think you're correct with using the input field for my situation, I just don't know why it's null.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a solution to my problem.

I ended up using a Flask session to hold the data from the last POST method

to save the data:

```
 session['car_model'] = 'model3'
```

and to retreive the data:

```
 carmodel = session.get('car_model', None)
```